# What kind of vpn tunnel is better for connect to Monero network: TCP or UDP?

Tags: cryptonote, network, vpn

I am using Monero daemon and downloading blockchain now. I use free vpn services and connect to vpn with OpenVpn with .ovpn config. I noticed that after 1 minute of work of Monero daemon speedtest shows 1.5-3 Mbps while I have 450-600 Mbps via vpn when do not run Monero daemon. And more, even when I stop monero daemon the speed is 3-5 Mbps. The speed restoring only when I reconnect to vpn.

That may be because of restrictions from free vpn provider that discovering strange garbage traffic from my pc. Or may be caused by bugs in CryptoNote and Levin algorithms used in Monero (I know there are problems with closing connections that make garbage in stack memory).

Is it possible to improve my network speed if i use tcp openvpn config instead of udp?